# No link works in my wordpress blog after I move it to another machine

Tags: php, wordpress

I move my blog www.erogol.com to another machine. After that, any link in my blog stopped working. Only if I changed the permalinks settings to default, links work with post_id urls.

I enabled apache rewrite option and my .htacces is as follows;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also deactivated all plugins and repair the db by using wordpress repair interface but nothing has changed.

Do you have something more to advice?

Edit: I keep my domain the same, only I changed the machine so the IP address.

Comment: you need to see how permeable links works in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

in Wordpress, the basis of URLs are stored in the database

So you must intervene on the **wp-options** table and update both fields "**WP_HOME**" and "**WP_SITEURL**" with the new domain name.

Comment: Correct, and if you can't access your DB or site admin, you can temporary override those from wp-config.php

Comment: as I told with the edit, I keep the domain name the same

Comment: there is no field wp_home or wp_siteurl on the table

Comment: rather you should look in the wp-options table for the lines when **option_name = siteurl** and **option_name = home** by updating the field **option_value** with your DNS